# Front-End for MySQL Forms (Windows or OSX)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, user-interface, crud

[Edit: I have awarded the bounty but not the question, as I feel there is still a chance for a better answer.]

I usually code my MySQL data entry interfaces in php.

But for quick projects where I would like to focus on the web side of things (pulling data from the database), I am looking for a **form front-end to MySQL.** Ideally, this would be an off-the-shelf Win or OSX program that I can hand over to a friend or client so she can input data into forms.

**An Example**

The lines above summarize the question, but here is a typical situation to showcase why "just give them phpMyAdmin" or some other web interface to MySQL generally wont work.

We have two main tables: images and albums. The third is an associative table that associates images with albums.

**Images:** id (PK), filename

**Albums:** id (PK), album

**Album_Image:** id (PK), imageid, albumid (these are foreign keys: the two id PKs from the Images and Albums tables)

For big projects, I don't mind coding a nice "back-end" interface (CRUD) that lets me edit data in a very comfortable, customized way.

For small projects, for instance an image gallery for a friend, I would like to be able to only program the "front-end": web interfaces that pull data from the database.
For the back-end, ideally, I would like to give my friend an off-the-shelf solution so she can enter images, albums, and associations between images and albums.
In the old days (I am thinking of DBaseIII), it was really easy to give interfaces to do that entry side of things.

Here is a crude approach I have tried. I have set up a view of the associative table joined to the parent tables, so it shows albumid, imageid (the PKs) and album, filename (associated fields in the parents) using this query:

```
SELECT albumid, imageid, album, filename FROM album_image axi
JOIN albums a ON a.`id` = axi.`albumid`
JOIN images i ON i.`id` = axi.`imageid`
```

The idea with this crude approach is that my friend would enter the parent PKs (albumid and imageid) in the associative table through the view, and that after hitting Insert, the full parent fields (filename and album) would be visible in the View for visual feedback. I have tried this view in three GUI tools: SQLyog (Win), HeidiSQL (Win) and Sequel Pro (OSX).

1. In Heidi and Sequel Pro, I have not found a way to edit the view.
2. In SQLyog, I can edit the PK fields (albumid and imageid) in the view, and the parent fields (album and filename) show properly when I hit "refresh". That's great. It works because even though the view shows three tables, we are only editing from one table. **But I cannot delete** a row as SQLyog doesn't know from which of the three tables we are trying to delete. On the other hand, in SQLyog, I able both able to insert and delete in a Query tab that contains the same query that creates the view, because in this kind of tab SQLyog allows me select the table being edited. So that works, but this workflow might start to be a little complex for my friend: she would have to open SQLyog, connect, open a saved query, select the right table to edit within the query, and make all the other right moves.

Wondering if any one knows an existing tool that is really good at making forms for MySQL---ideally a Windows or OSX binary. I will consider a web solution, but I am not interested in a framework---the key is speed of deployment, and if we went the framework route I would be better off making the interface with my own CRUD libraries. Again, I can code it, but my goal with these kinds of "quickie projects" is to focus my workload on the front end (web interface to the database), leaving the back end to an off-the-shelf tool.

Thanks heaps in advance for any insights. :)

Edit: I see that no one has mentioned Navicat or MySQL Workbench. I haven't tried either, wondering if someone knows off the top of their head whether they would do the trick.

Comment: Have you considered [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

Comment: Yes. I haven't done much in phpmyadmin in a while, but I doubt it will make it easy to edit an associative table via a view.

Comment: Isn't the bigger issue with the workflow complexity here the idea that your friend will add or remove images by entering some IDs, without a helpful thumbnail? 

And what of position within an album?

Comment: @Paul Gregory, for a full-blown GUI, you are quite correct that these features would be very nice. For what my friend is doing, these features are not a big deal. For placement, she will rank images from 0 to 1000 and there will be sorting options on date, tags, location etc. Also I have been tutoring her and her husband on computer skills and would like to get them involved in the workings of the database. Eventually I will probably use my CRUD libraries and drop a perfect web GUI into their lap, but for right now I am really interested in a quick-start with an off-the-shelf solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a **form front-end** for MySQL.

Since it sounds like you are more interested in binaries than web apps, have you looked into Microsoft Access? It can talk to MySQL and could be just what you need.

Open Office Base may not have quite the features you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have found the right words with "form front-end". I edited the question a bit to reflect that. I'll take a look at Access---it will be strange after 15 years.

Comment: I connected to the database in Access. [For anyone following: installed the 32-bit ODBC connector from the MySQL website, set up the DSN by running C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. Access: Blank Database, External, ODBC, Linked Tables]. I was able to create a form that accomplishes just what I wanted: adding and deleting from the associative table, while showing fields from the joined tables. I can select the Album and Image with a pull-down. Lots to learn in Access, but so far this is the best solution. Looking forward to any other insights / solutions anyone may have.

Comment: Ah, but there is no MS Access in OSX... That's sad, as Access front-ends run on Windows machines that don't have Access through the free Access run-time. Any cross-platform thoughts will be greatly appreciated. I will have a look at Libre Office Base, though I hear it is primitive compared to MS Access.

Comment: Update: Installed LibreOffice Base and connected to the database. Forms were greyed out. Researched that, solution = install whole LibreOffice suite for forms to work. Tried creating forms with the Forms Wizard, could not make a form that does the job specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the solution, your attempt at making things simpler is creating the complication.

There is no benefit to your friend in adding album images in a view if that view that only shows the filename and album title after they have entered the IDs and clicked Insert.

Before adding an image, your friend needs to know the album ID and the image ID. This information may not be in the view. She will therefore look at the album table and look at the image table to find this information, cross-referencing the filename with her own list of uploaded images.

Then, having written these two numbers down, she can insert a row directly into the album_image.

For visual feedback, she can check the frontend website.

It is true that a view showing the album name and filename would make deleting entries easier, but I would assume that images and albums are added much more frequently than they are deleted.

The ability to edit an associative table in a view that shows linked information, therefore, should not greatly affect your choice of tool. I could suggest tools, and phpMyAdmin is a logical choice, particularly if it is desirable to teach your friend computer skills that are widely applicable. It appears you have already identified some executable tools.

I imagine that you could add some additional hidden frontend views that could make your friend's workflow easier, such as a list of images and IDs that aren't in albums, a list of album IDs, or a view that shows the IDs. I do recommend you consider extending the frontend with a simple login and Edit options using your CRUD library, rather than devising a separate backend GUI.

I appreciate this is not an answer to the exact question, but it does resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer, I appreciate your thoughts. You may well be right that the best GUI solution is already in my hands. In that case it seems to me that there is a gap here for someone to fill, as adding these feature to a GUI tool seems somewhat basic, and would be helpful in a number of similar cases---focus on the front end, give your cheap client an off-the-shelf solution for data entry. I haven't looked at MS Access in 15 years but I am fairly confident that this (intuitive editing of associative tables) is among the functions that would be core to the program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be helpful or not.  I was hoping to find a UI with some eye candy/styling, but while searching I stumbled upon this:

https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/introducing_mysql_for_excel

> As part of the new product initiatives of the MySQL on Windows group we released a tool that makes the task of getting data in and out of a MySQL Database very friendly and intuitive, and we paired it with one of the preferred applications for data analysis and manipulation in Windows platforms, MS Excel.

Like I said, not sure if it will help.  I'm in a similar situation - low-tech, low budget  client.  The difference is my weakness in MySQL, but for me I just need a single table, so I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool that will allow you delete such values from such a view, not for mysql, since `For a multiple-table updatable view ... DELETE is not supported`, see [Updatable and Insertable Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html)

Comment: As mentioned in the post, there is such a tool, since I am able to do it in SQLyog. Remember that while the View shows three tables, we are only inserting into one of the three tables. Deleting is where it gets hairy, because the tool needs to know which of the three tables to delete from.

Comment: No worries. > see my updated answer. Okay. To keep the convo clear, the original said "There is no tool that will allow you to insert such values"

Comment: @playful Initially I was thinking that you are trying to insert data into two tables behing the view, since that is not supported also.

Comment: >There is no tool that will allow you delete such values from such a view
@dan For the record there are such tools. That's exactly what I (and many others) code when we make CRUDs that show views of joined tables with a delete button next to a row. The program logic knows that when you hit delete, the record is deleted from the associative table. This function could easily exist in a binary GUI tool: you'd have a pull-down menu to specify which table to target for the delete. That's exactly how it works when you delete from the query tab in SQLyog, but they haven't implemented it for views.

Comment: @playful Sure, there are a lot of ways to meet your goals, I was just saying that there is no tool to **delete entries form a view** that is using multiple tables.

Comment: For the record, a hypothetical tool is not a tool that exists, nor is custom code a generic tool.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the equivelent of the Python based Django admin system which practically builds itself from analysis of the data structure.

Frameworks like Symfony, Cake and Yii have some of this built in, however I'm guessing that your database architecture may not be compatable as these types of systems normally require you to stick to strict naming conventions, but it's certainly worth taking a look.

Comment: Hi Sqoo, thanks for sharing your thoughts. 
>these types of systems normally require you to stick to strict naming conventions 
Yes, I'm sure frameworks are wonderful for some needs but I've managed to avoid them so far, and I'd like to stay on that path.

Comment: I can understand why (having built a couple of MVC frameworks in the past) but the sheer convenience and amount of functionality available at your fingertips has changed my mind. I would recommend taking a look at codeigniter as an example of how unobtrusive a good MVC framework can be, especially if you add an ORM to the mix

Answer (score 0):

Playful,

I already posted one answer, but this one is different enough to merit a seperate response, IMO.

Since you are looking for a simple, client-friendly solution, may I suggest Adminer?
http://www.adminer.org/en/?

Specifically, I used the Wordpress plugin here on a site recently:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminer/

It provides pretty much full phpMyAdmin funcitonality.  Very easy for the client, and if they want to, they can export the database as .csv and edit in excel, then re-upload.  Just about everyone is familiar with editing in Excel, and they can make backups regularly.

Hope this helps!

J

Answer (score 0):

You can very quickly and easily make a front-end for this type of use with Xataface. I find it very quick and useful. I would be happy to help you get going with it.

www.xataface.com